# GLTF Loader Trial Returning TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, three.js, model, gltf

Im fairly new at three.js and am trying to load a model into my canvas. as soon as I import the GLTFLoader, I get the above reading in the console. What is going on? The syntax and relative paths looks fine. I dont really understand whats going on. I added another folder to put the master three.js folder into but it is not working.

```js
import * as THREE from '../master/three.js-master/build/three.module.js'
import {GLTFLoader} from '../master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl')
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load('../assets/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
  console.log(gltf);
  const root = gltf.scene;
  scene.add(root);
}, function(xhr){
  console.log((xhr.loaded/xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")
}, function(error){
  console.log('error');
})

// const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
//   color: 'green'
// })

const boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
scene.add(boxMesh)

//Boiler Plate

const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
}

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width/sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.set(0,1,2)
scene.add(camera)

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas
})

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
// renderer.outputEncoding = true
renderer.render(scene, camera)


console.log('working')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <script type = "module" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `r137` using ES6 modules like `GLTFLoader` in the browser requires an import map. Add the following section right below you `canvas`.

```
<!-- Import maps polyfill -->
<!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "../master/three.js-master/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `three.js` import statement in your `scripts.js` looks like so then:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
```