# Failed to resolve module specifier "three" as of 137

Tags: javascript, three.js, skypack-cdn

Coming back to some old project, I discover nothing was loading. Checking the console log I see the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

In my script I got the following:

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/build/three.module.js"
import { OBJLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js"
import { FirstPersonControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js"
```

I try to step back some versions and not until I reach `0.136.0` does this error go away. Has the way one imports `three.js` changed, or is this a bug?

Also, would there be some way of catching this at runtime? Like I get the latest version number from Skypack and try an import. If failed, automatically step back a decimal and try again.

**Edit**
@Mugen87 offers using `importmap`. I change my code with the following:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "three": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/build/three.module.js",
        "three/OBJLoader": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js",
        "three/FirstPersonControls": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js"
    }
}
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three"
import { OBJLoader } from "three/OBJLoader"
import { FirstPersonControls } from "three/FirstPersonControls"
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/-/three@v0.137.5-HJEdoVYPhjkiJWkt6XIa/dist=es2019,mode=raw/build/three.module.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71047538/5250847

Comment: @Mugen87 I got an error when I tried that.

Comment: You only have to define the import for `three`. Not for `OBJLoader` and `FirstPersonControls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN you're using (cdn.skypack.dev) does some re-exporting on their side, which is causing the problem.

The file you're referencing in your import isn't actually the three.js module, but a re-direct.

That file does an `export *` (which is fine), AND an `export {default}`, which is where the failure is occurring. Three.js does not have a `default` export.

Skypack is likely applying this redirect universally to all modules, so it's not that they necessarily KNOW this is happening, but they should definitely be testing their system before hosting a specific module...

Try changing your `importmap` to reference the following URL, and it should work:

```
https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/three@v0.137.5-HJEdoVYPhjkiJWkt6XIa/dist=es2019,mode=raw/build/three.module.js
```

Comment: Ok, I see... Well, I did a little `php`ing and got the `export *` link so that I would always be importing from the latest version. Time to apply this everywhere.

Comment: Oh, hold on. Now `GLTFLoader.js` is unable to resolve 'three'.

Comment: @Edward I missed a word in my answer, and it will probably fix things... Change the `import`s in your code back to `three`, and change your import **map** to reference the URL above.

Comment: Ah, there we go.... and `importmap` is not compatible with Firefox... Yes, I did look things up, and adding the shims did not seem to help. But all is fine on Chrome.

Comment: @Edward Yes, unfortunately `importmap` is still just a draft, which means it might not even make it into the final spec. But it's definitely a convenient way to test and debug code before it gets run through a builder.